# Can twig be used for generating non-PHP code?

Tags: twig

I use twig with the Symfony framework for web development and really like the way standard sections can be modified depending on requirements. My question is, I have to write a lot of code for statistical analysis in other programming languages.

Is there a reason why I only see twig used for generating html/php code? Or could I just use twig for templating code in other languages to generate ad-hoc programs depending on requirements?

For example, I'm thinking of a web-front end where I have a form with custom fields and combobox's populated from my database that I can submit to then present me with my compiled twig template code that I view/download. Would this be the right way to go about it?

Comment: Jinja for Python ? :)

Comment: You should be able to find similar templating tool kits in other languages.

Comment: I've successfully used twig to generate latex output, so yes, you can use it to generate stuff other than html.

Comment: Thanks @Maerlyn, that's the kind of thing I was looking for....do you have any tips/techniques for generating/displaying the output? If so, would be great if you could post them as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my projects I needed to generate LaTeX output with twig (which then was converted to a pdf). Back then I had to hack in a custom escaper, now you have a [supported way](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html#custom-escapers) of doing that.

There really is nothing special to say. Twig works beautifully whether your output is html, xml, csv, latex, matlab code or whatever :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple : no you can not use Twig to generate non-PHP code. When you type a `{{ variable }}`, it is translated in something like `<?php echo $var ?>` and that's the way this templating engine works.

However you can use it with other PHP frameworks than Symfony, and other templating engines exist for other languages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I was wondering if that was the case but @Maerlyn's comment gives me some hope of what I'm trying to achieve